# Why the "finish" button on the ObjectDataSource's Wizard is always disabled?

Tags: asp.net, objectdatasource

I'm using the **ObjectDataSource** Control. Below is how I have decorated the classe I'me about to use with the Datasource control.

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataObject]
public class LoadAndUploadPhoto
{
  [System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute
  (System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Insert, true)]
  public bool SaveImage(int number)
  {
    //implement here...
  }
}
```

When trying to configure the ObjectDataSource, I can see the both the **LoadAndUploadPhoto** and the **SaveImage** method on the dropdownList.

Unfortunately, the button "**Finish**" is disabled. Is there anything I am missing?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of the wizard?

Comment: Use Alt-PrintScreen on your keyboard to capture screenshot.  Open Microsoft Paint and Paste.  Then Save as a file on your computer.  Upload using an image host like http://imageshack.us/.  Finally, link to the image in your post, or include it directly using the img wizard (looks like a picture frame in the post editor)

Comment: Is the Next button also disabled??

Comment: yes, the next button also is disabled

Answer (score 1):

Are you specifying a parameter source?  Did you give it a property name?

Comment: Unfortunately, not only the finish button is disabled, but also the next button that'd let me go to the next step and define the property name, is also disabled.